# How to access Job DSL's readFileFromWorkspace from a helper class?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a large number of Jenkins job definitions in Job DSL that all rely on some common functionality that I implemented in helper classes. This is the essence of the `jobDsl` step running these scripts:

```
jobDsl {
  additionalClasspath('jobdsl/src/main/groovy')
  targets('jobdsl/*.groovy')
  sandbox(true)
}
```

One of the helper classes in `jobdsl/src/main/groovy` needs to read a file from the workspace, but it cannot access the `readFileFromWorkspace` function.

So this one wouldn't work:

```
class MyHelper {
  static Closure processFile(String src) {
    ...
    def txt = readFileFromWorkspace(src)
    ...
  }
}
```

I have to take a closure parameter instead:

```
class MyHelper {
  static Closure processFile(String src, Closure rffw) {
    ...
    def txt = rffw(src)
    ...
  }
}
```

Which makes the code calling this helper bloated:

```
MyHelper.processFile('foo.txt', { readFileFromWorkspace(it) })
```

Is there a way to make my class see `readFileFromWorkspace`? Actually, I couldn't even figure out to which class does this function belong to. Or whether is it a real function at all or something "magicly" defined by the DSL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HelperClass is present in other file which is out of Job-dsl context. So to make it visible, try doing as below.

```
class MyHelper {
   static Closure processFile(String src, def dslFactory) {
   ...
   def txt = dslFactory.readFileFromWorkspace(src)
   ...
   }
}

MyHelper.processFile('foo.txt', this)
```

The above code should work for you, else please revert to me if you encounter any problems.

Comment: This one works indeed. I guess there's no way to completely get rid of the second argument though?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Please mark this as an answer or upvote it if it has solved your problem.